# Why can't I assign values to the array elements?

Tags: c, pointers, types

In this C-program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct mystruct
{};

int
main()
{
  struct mystruct* obj = malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct));
  struct mystruct(*list)[10];
  list[0] = obj;
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to create a fixed size array of pointers (which point to some struct).

The last line of `main` results in the error "expression must be a modifiable lvalue". But why?

I know you're not allowed to assign to arrays, but I don't want to assign to an array, I want  to assign to a pointer.

Comment: `list[0]` is an array, an array of `struct mystruct`.  Try `list[0][0] = *obj;` to assign the first element of the array.

Comment: " to create a fixed size array of pointers " --> `struct mystruct *list_alt[10];` ,makes more sense.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `list[0][0] = …` would write through an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a fixed size array of pointers

But you aren't: you're creating a pointer to a fixed-size array of structures. You can use [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/) to assist you with the syntax of complex types.

```
cdecl> explain struct mystruct(*list)[10];
declare list as pointer to array 10 of struct mystruct
cdecl> explain struct mystruct *list[10];
declare list as array 10 of pointer to struct mystruct
```

The error messages from GCC and Clang are clearer than your compiler. Consider using multiple compilers to get more feedback about your code.

```
% gcc -Wall -O a.c
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:11:11: error: assignment to expression with array type
   11 |   list[0] = obj;
      |           ^
$ clang -Wall -O a.c
a.c:11:11: error: array type 'struct mystruct [10]' is not assignable
  list[0] = obj;
  ~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct mystruct (*list)[10];
```

creates `list` as a pointer to a 10-element array of `struct mystruct`.  What you want is

```
struct mystruct *list[10];
```

which creates `list` as a 10-element array of pointers to `struct mystruct`.  Those parentheses change the meaning completely.  Now your

```
list[0] = obj;
```

statement should work.